# Height doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, height

I have Firefox 25.0 and my `div` is not getting the correct height.
In my css:

```
#page {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    width: 98%;
    height: 87%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1%;
    top: 12%;
    display: table;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

When the window becomes too small, the height exceeds 87%

I have tried a jQuery alternative:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var contentheight = $("#most").height();
    var contentheightt = contentheight * .87;
    contentheightt = contentheightt+"px";
    $("#page").css("height",contentheightt);
});
```

Neither work in Firefox but it works in Safari and Chrome.

Here is my page: http://sdgr.comule.com/sd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the firefox, you need to add following css in your #page.txt class -

```
position: absolute; 
overflow-y: scroll; 
left: 500px;
```

change left value as per the requirement.

Comment: Thank you for this help. Adding those few lets me modify the height with jQuery for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

On css height in percentage is not working correctly
Try to use a min-height not in percentage
You could also try $(window).height () in jquery
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The #page div expands with the inner div, which contains your content. If you set the following div to `position: absolute;` your problem should be fixed.

```
<div id="desc" class="col txt"></div>
```